# Can I specify in .css file the tooltip text for objects of a certain class?

Tags: css, tooltip

I have a number of objects of class abc (and some that are not)

```
<img src="..." class="abc">
<img src="..." class="abc">
<img src="...">
<img src="..." class="abc">
```

I would like to set (just once) the tooltip text for everything of class abc.  So something like this in my CSS file:

```
img.abc {
  tooltip-text : "click me, you fool!" ;
}
```

Of course, tooltip-text does not seem to be a valid piece of CSS.  Is there some way to accomplish this?

Online searching mostly reveals ways to customize the styling of tooltips, and as part of that can set the text.  But these seem overkill.

I can do this in javascript:

```
    elems = document.getElementsByClassName('abc') ;
    for( i=0 ; i<elems.length ; i++ ) {
    elems[i].title = "click me, you fool!" ;
    }
```

but I would prefer a CSS solution.

I know I can put

```
<img src="..." title="click me, you fool!">
```

everywhere, but that makes changing the text hard.  I'd rather have to only have the tooltip text entered in one place.

Answer (score 0):

to create tooltip the best way is using `::before` and `::after` element. But these pseudo-class don't work on `img` tag (i don't finde the explaination in de W3C).
So you have to us JS or includ them in other tag (div, li etc)

html:

```html
<ul>
    <li class="abc">Visible Tooltip</li>
    <li class="abc"><img class="abc" src="https://i.imgur.com/ApaPK60.png" alt="">
    </li>
    <li class="abc"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ApaPK60.png" alt=""></li>
    <li class="abc"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ApaPK80.png" alt=""></li>
    <li><img class="abc img-pseudo" src="https://i.imgur.com/R3zjOZK.jpeg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

style.scss:

```scss
$color_1: #79b70e;
$color_2: #44593a;
$color_3:  #ff8700;
img {
  width: 150px;
}
ul{
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.abc {
  position: relative;
  &::after,
  &::before {
    background-color: $color_2;
    position: absolute;
  }

  &::after {
    content: 'bas';
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: $color_3;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9;
    font-weight: bold;
    // define the position
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 10px));
  }

  &::before {
    content: ' ';
    display: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    z-index: 9;

    // define the position
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 5px)) rotate(45deg);
  }

  &:hover::after,
  &:hover::before {
    display: block;
  }
}
.img-pseudo{
  padding: 20px;
  background: $color_1;
}
```

output.css:

```css
img {
  width: 150px; }

ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px; }

.abc {
  position: relative; }
  .abc::after, .abc::before {
    background-color: #44593a;
    position: absolute; }
  .abc::after {
    content: 'bas';
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #ff8700;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 9;
    font-weight: bold;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 10px)); }
  .abc::before {
    content: ' ';
    display: none;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    z-index: 9;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, calc(100% + 5px)) rotate(45deg); }
  .abc:hover::after, .abc:hover::before {
    display: block; }

.img-pseudo {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #79b70e; }
```